# AMCharts Force Directed Tree adding javascript function to children

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I have a Force Directed Tree created with AmCharts and i would like to add a javascript function to display a text below whenever i click on children items.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq1IU.png)

For instance, when i click on Safari, i would like to insert a short description about Safari in a div that has its id set to "description".

I'm pretty new in javascript coding :/ I have tried to insert a listener but i,m not sure it is the right thing to do...

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries());

// Set data
series.data = [{
  "name": "Chrome",
    "value": 12,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_chrome.svg",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_chrome.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Firefox",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_firefox.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Internet Explorer",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_ie.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Safari",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_safari.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Opera",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_opera.svg"
  }]
}];

// Set up data fields
series.dataFields.value = "value";
series.dataFields.name = "name";
series.dataFields.id = "id";
series.dataFields.children = "children";
series.dataFields.linkWith = "link";

// Add labels
series.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}";
series.nodes.template.label.valign = "bottom";
series.nodes.template.label.fill = am4core.color("#000");
series.nodes.template.label.dy = 10;
series.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{value}[/]";
series.fontSize = 10;
series.minRadius = 30;
series.maxRadius = 90;

// Configure circles
series.nodes.template.circle.disabled = true;

// Configure icons
var icon = series.nodes.template.createChild(am4core.Image);
icon.propertyFields.href = "image";
icon.horizontalCenter = "middle";
icon.verticalCenter = "middle";
icon.width = 60;
icon.height = 60;


series.centerStrength = 0.2;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      /*background-color:#e1e3e6;*/
    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dataviz.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>

<div class="row inner-b-lg">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add `series.nodes.template.events.on("up", function (event){//});` click event handler
2. use property `dataItem` to get your detail properties `name` or `value`
3. set the information to a `div`

like this modified example:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries());

// Set data
series.data = [{
  "name": "Chrome",
    "value": 12,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_chrome.svg",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_chrome.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Firefox",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_firefox.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Internet Explorer",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_ie.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Safari",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_safari.svg"
  }, {
    "name": "Opera",
    "value": 1,
    "image": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/icon_opera.svg"
  }]
}];

// Set up data fields
series.dataFields.value = "value";
series.dataFields.name = "name";
series.dataFields.id = "id";
series.dataFields.children = "children";
series.dataFields.linkWith = "link";

// Add labels
series.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}";
series.nodes.template.label.valign = "bottom";
series.nodes.template.label.fill = am4core.color("#000");
series.nodes.template.label.dy = 10;
series.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{value}[/]";
series.fontSize = 10;
series.minRadius = 30;
series.maxRadius = 90;

// Configure circles
series.nodes.template.circle.disabled = true;

// Configure icons
var icon = series.nodes.template.createChild(am4core.Image);
icon.propertyFields.href = "image";
icon.horizontalCenter = "middle";
icon.verticalCenter = "middle";
icon.width = 60;
icon.height = 60;


series.centerStrength = 0.2;

series.nodes.template.events.on("up", function (event) {
   var node = event.target;
   var name = node.dataItem.name;
   var value = node.dataItem.value;

   var elem = document.querySelector('#your-select-node');
   var html = elem.innerHTML;
   elem.innerHTML = name + ': ' + value;
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      /*background-color:#e1e3e6;*/
    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dataviz.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>

<div class="row inner-b-lg">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="your-select-node">
    </div>
</div>
```